# Failed to Send Emails From My Laravel Application Using Cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, email, cpanel

I'm trying to send 2 emails when user will submit the contact form.
1 should be sent to the user email & the other should be sent to my own email.
My `.env` file look like this:

```
MAIL_MAILER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=m.s***********@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD='************'
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=m.s***********@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

I'm sending the emails from controller like this:

```
dd($request->email);
Mail::to($request->email)->bcc('info@my-domain.com')->send(new ContactSubmit($contact));
```

I'm receiving all the emails on `info@my-domain.com` but not receiving on any other domain.
`dd($request->email);` is showing me correct emails.

Before I was trying to send emails from my own domain:

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=info@my-domain.com
```

But I was receiving this error in my inbox:

> SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data:
> 552 5.2.0 xkfupRYgo20R2xkfupkpjt :CPANEL: Access to this mail system has been blocked for xh******** due to spam activity. Spam was
> seen coming from this account, and possibly other scripts running in
> it. For help resolving the issue, see http://x.co/spamclean. Once the
> compromise has been cleaned, please contact customer support to remove
> the block.

The output of `$request` is something like this:

```
Illuminate\Http\Request {#43 ▼
  #json: null
  #convertedFiles: null
  #userResolver: Closure($guard = null) {#312 ▶}
  #routeResolver: Closure() {#303 ▶}
  +attributes: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#45 ▶}
  +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#44 ▼
    #parameters: array:6 [▼
      "_token" => "BfBF3cKMD2WWYEc1AGHbYgFS1KYo2R6MkIRwTYWH"
      "name" => "Muhammad Shahzaib"
      "email" => "shahzaib.example@gmail.com"
      "phone" => "05000000000"
      "message" => "Testing"
      "g-recaptcha-response" => null
    ]
  }
  +query: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#51 ▶}
  +server: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ServerBag {#47 ▶}
  +files: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag {#48 ▶}
  +cookies: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#46 ▶}
  +headers: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag {#49 ▶}
  #content: null
  #languages: null
  #charsets: null
  #encodings: null
  #acceptableContentTypes: null
  #pathInfo: "/contact-us"
  #requestUri: "/contact-us"
  #baseUrl: ""
  #basePath: null
  #method: "POST"
  #format: null
  #session: Illuminate\Session\Store {#1622 ▶}
  #locale: null
  #defaultLocale: "en"
  -preferredFormat: null
  -isHostValid: true
  -isForwardedValid: true
  -isSafeContentPreferred: null
  basePath: ""
  format: "html"
}
```

Comment: Well you have the answer already!

Comment: can you please point it the mistake that I'm doing?

Comment: I made the answer in your question easier to read, do you see it now?

Comment: I already tried it but its not helping me. Because even if I send email using my gmail account, I'm not receiving it.

Comment: Shouldn't fail for Gmail. Could you post the output of request here (partial only)

Comment: Looks like your server sent out spam. This is not a problem of PHP or Laravel (unless these were used to send out that spam)